# Create a list of tuples dynamically in C#

Tags: c#, list, tuples

I want to add to a C# list of tuples declared as

```
var myList = List<(int, int)>();
```

How can I do this? The method `Add` *doesn't accept* **2** arguments. The code computes **2** integers in a `for` loop. I want to check in each loop whether the generated **2** integers already exist in `myList` and, if not, add it to `myList`.

Comment: No, `Add` doesn't accept 2 arguments - but it'll accept *one* argument which is a tuple, e.g. `myList.Add((1, 2));`

Comment: You may want to use `HashSet<(int, int)>` instead of `List<(int, int)>`; `HashSet` contains unique items only, so you don't have to do any check, `Add((1, 2));` will be enough

Comment: To add to what @DmitryBychenko said, lookups in `HashSet<T>` are O(1) compared to O(n) for `List<T>`. That'll make your "does it already exist?" check much faster, assuming you have more than just a few items in the list.

Comment: *"I want to check in each loop whether the generated 2 integers already exist"* Do you mean together, in a single tuple (and in a specific order)? Showing some code might clarify exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"The method Add doesn't accept 2 arguments"*

Correct, but you can pass a `Tuple<int, int>` as a single argument to the list, since that's the type that the list contains.

> *"The code computes 2 integers in a for loop. I want to check in each loop whether the generated 2 integers already exist in myList and, if not, add it to myList"*

Some code would help here, but I would suggest creating a `Tuple<int, int>` from the two integers and then checking if that tuple already exists in the list or not (`Tuple` overrides `Equals` to compare the values of it's items with the corresponding items in the other `Tuple`, so there's no extra work to do):

```
// We have two computed integers
int first = 5;
int second = 8;

// Add them as a Tuple to the list if it doesn't already exist
if (!myList.Contains((first, second))) myList.Add((first, second));
```

Comment: OP is using a value tuple syntax `(int, int)`